# Does the correspondence between global derivations and vector fields hold for complex manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

For smooth manifolds, there is a correspondence
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
\text { derivations on } \\
\text { algebra of smooth functions } \\
\text { on } X
\end{array}\right\} \simeq\left\{\begin{array}{c}
\text { smooth } \\
\text { tangent vector fields } \\
\text { on } X
\end{array}\right\}
$$
which is actually an isomorphism of real Lie algebras. Does the analogous result hold for complex manifolds?

Comment: The proof depends on the existence of bump functions. So of course it holds in the smooth category for complex manifolds, but cannot hold in the holomorphic category.

Comment: The proof on ncatlab does, but I hoped there was another proof. Do you know about something more in the complex case? Can I recover a partial result, as in a Lie algebra morphism in one of the two directions, are there easy counterexamples, etc.?

Comment: For starters, in the holomorphic category, in the case of compact $X$ there are no nonconstant holomorphic functions, and there may or may not be (nontrivial) global holomorphic vector fields. Perhaps you should start there.

Comment: Can you say more precisely what correspondence you are looking for?